# How to remove the title reprinting again above

Tags: .net, maui

How to remove that title is displaying above again. When I change the first shell content to another one it will show that title in above....?

```
<Shell>

 <Tab Grid.Column="0" >

 <ShellContent Title="ShoePolish" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ShoePolish}" />

 <ShellContent Title="WISBook" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:WISBook}" />

 <ShellContent Title="BodyLotion" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BodyLotion}" />

</Tab>

</Shell>
```

[image]

Comment: "ShoePolish" is the "title" of that ShellContent page. You could do `TItle=""`, but I suspect you'd then have an empty rectangle. I don't see an API in Tab or ShellContent that can suppress that title row.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it is not empty rectangle, the whole row is not rendered. I have application on MAUI with tabs, as long as you set the title to the tabs, and not to the content, and do not use the "automatic wrapper", you will have just one row with tabs.

Answer (score 2):

The "title reprint" is your tab.
Most likely you want TabBar there.

```
<TabBar>
        <Tab Title="1">
            <ShellContent        
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="2">
            <ShellContent        
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
        </Tab>

</TabBar>
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, trying to make a point here.

When you define TabBar, and set the titles of the Tabs, you will have one row, with the titles only.

When you set the Title to the ShellContent, above the TabBar you will have this row, with the title of the first ShellContent.

IF something is not clear, please ask.

Comment: How can I remove shoepolish sub heading from above tabs? any suggestions?

Comment: @DanulHiviVihan I have added the code you need.

Comment: I added but it still didn't work. when I added the code you suggested it showed nothing in the tabs. it shows like it doesn't contain tabs.

Comment: What can I do about that thing?

Comment: I want to see your WHOLE shell xaml, and screenshot of what you see.

Comment: Use the below GitHub repo and use vihan branch. that is the updated code. https://github.com/Industrial-BlueLotus/SimplePOS.git

Comment: What I see in the github: <ShellContent Title="Login". What did I say: Setting the title of ShellContent makes this bar render.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested. Added a title to the tab and removed the title from shell content and also added shellcontents inside of some tabs tags. But didn't work. That is why I changed again. have you tried with your suggestion...? is it working with you?'

Comment: @DanulHiviVihan it is not a suggestion. It is working code from my app. Copy paste it, you will see one row, two tabs. One says "1" the other says "2" , no title bar.